# Deleting item in IndexedDB while using autoIncrement

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb

I am trying to implement this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325135/Getting-Started-with-IndexedDB).

Everything works fine until I attempt to delete a certain item.

Using this:

```
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
      console.log("upgrade", event);

      db = event.target.result;
      console.log("db", db);

      if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains("chatBot")) {
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("chatBot", {keyPath: "timeStamp", autoIncrement: true});
      }
    };
```

and setting up the deletion:

```
btnDelete.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var id, transaction, objectStore, request;

      id = document.getElementById("txtID").value;
      console.log("id", typeof id);

      transaction = db.transaction("people", "readwrite");
      objectStore = transaction.objectStore("people");
      request = objectStore.delete(id);
      request.onsuccess = function(evt) {
        console.log("deleted content");
      };
    }, false);
```

There is no problem adding items to the indexedDB but for some reason I can't figure out why it can't delete the items.

The `id` is a string and the `objectStore.delete(id)` is the correct implementation.

Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2Va9DksV) of the example

Using Firefox 18

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using autoIncrement key, the key is generated by the user agent. In FF and Chrome, it is integer starting with 1.   If you give valid key and convert your `id` to integer, your code run fine. I tested in both FF and Chrome (dartium). `'1'` and `1` are different keys according to IndexedDB API key definition.

Another issue IndexedDB API design. The delete methods always [return to success](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-steps-for-deleting-records-from-an-object-store) event handler with `undefined` as result whether given key was deleted or not. So it is very difficult to debug. I think it should return number of deleted records at least.

[Edit] mod code: http://pastebin.com/mLpU0VfP
[Edit... also] Notice the `+` which converts the `string` to an `integer`
`request = db.transaction("people", "readwrite").objectStore("people").delete(+id);`

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I didn't know autoIncrement had this peculiarity.  Can you provide a source?  I would like to learn more about such pitfalls... it would save me A LOT of time.  Thank again!!

Comment: Updated. I have quite extensive usage guide for indexeddb http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/getting-started.html it is more on exploiting indexeddb api rather than pitfalls. especially key has a lot of useful tricks.

Comment: Thanks Kyaw Tun... I've been experimenting with IndexedDB and collecting my own info but it seems I can learn a lot from what you got!!